# Plot line and bar on single chart

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I want to plot "cummax" on my bar chart for MACD histogram. I have tried the following but it is giving the error.

```
ax =btc_1h["hist_1h"][-204:].plot(kind='bar', figsize=(10, 6))
ax = plt.axhline(y=btc_1h["hist_1h_cumax"][-204:], ls="dotted")
```

It gives the following error

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),
> a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

please guide

Comment: Which line is the error? Can you pls post a few sample lines for `btc_1h` as text (not pic) using edit and pasting it there... If it is in `axhline()`, would think it is because matplotlib is expecting one value - like 0.5 or 20, but you are providing a series `btc_1h["hist_1h_cumax"][-204:]`

Comment: Apart from that, don't assign `ax = plt.axhline(...)` as that will make the variable `ax` unusable.

Comment: error is I can not post cummax() because it keeps changing.